# No overload for 'button' matches delegate 'EventHandler';

Tags: c#, winforms

Fairly new to using windows forums and im running into the problem of using intergers over multiple methods, while searching for a solution i changed the method from

```
    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

To this

```
    public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e, int attack1, int hp2)
```

This works fine in this view, but the Designer tab is giving off the error "No overload for 'button_click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'.
The intergers are created within the constructor of that forum. Is there a solution to fix that problem or is there a better way to use the integers between the methods

Comment: Why do you want these parameters in an event handler, and who do you think will be providing values for them when the user clicks the button?

Comment: That's because this is hooked up to the click event for your button, which has a specific signature - it only takes an object and an EventArgs

Comment: The event raised from the buttons is `object, EventArgs`, you should subscribe to the button using its regular signature and raise a new custom `EventHandler` with the desired parameters/arguments.

Comment: If you know in the button click event what the values for attack1 and hp2 will be, then from that event you can call another method and pass those values to it.

Comment: You aren't ever going to call `button_click` yourself (if you do, then you're doing it wrong).  So there won't ever be a chance to pass your own variables.

Answer (score 0):

Event handler should exactly match signature of delegate - i.e. type and count of parameters and type of return value should be same as defined for event delegate. `ButtonClick` event has type of `EventHandler` delegate. That delegate is defined as

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Handlers which you attach to event should have exactly same signature - `void (object, EventArgs)`.

And even if it would be possible to use handlers with different signatures, you have forgotten that event is raised by `Button` instance. How button will know which value to provide for additional method parameters? It knows nothing about attack and hp. And you cannot modify button class implementation to pass some additional arguments for you.

If you want to use some additional values in event handler, you should store those values as form fields:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
   private int attack;
   private int hp;

   public Form1()
   {
       // initialize attack and hp here
   }

   private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // attack and hp avalilable here
   }
}
```

Or you can store some information in `Tag` property of button and retrieve that information from event's sender:

```
   private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var button = (Button)sender;
       // use button.Tag
   }
```

Comment: You could expand your answers suggesting a new event with the desired signature

Comment: @bradbury9 -- The OPs code is not ever going to call the delegate -- the button click event from the winforms sub system does.  So what would you do with your new event?

Comment: So my best option is to create a new public method to initialise the ints instead of initialising in the constructor?

Comment: @Minimarshman why? Code above shows initialization in constructor

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy so my ints are created in the constructor and then i should assign a value in public Form1, because currently they are assigned values in a switch statement that checks what attack is being used. Also writing private before seems to cause alot of errors of different types

Comment: @Minimarshman sorry, I don't understand you. Use class fields

Comment: My terms are probably completely wrong as i dont fully understand alot of this yet, thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @Minimarshman you can read about class fields and how to use them https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396